# Is it grammatically correct to ask 'what do you mean [word/phrase]?'?

Tags: grammar, spoken-english

I often hear something like 'what do you mean "gone"?' I've been wondering whether the omission of the preposition 'by' ('what do you mean *[by]* "gone"?') complies with the grammar rules.

Comment: John: Mario's gone. Philip: What do you mean "gone"? John: I mean he has left the premises and won't be back. [For example]. Context is everything. Resistance is futile.

Answer (score 0):

While it may not be strictly grammatical, it is idiomatic, and is generally preferred over the grammatical form, unless you wish to be formal or very emphatic.

Comment: And, of course, it doesn't mean "What does _gone_ mean?", but "Why are you saying that - what has happened?"

Comment: It is grammatical because it is heard and would be written in quote marks.